# upload file nodejs and angular formidable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, formidable

I use formidable to upload file with angular and nodejs. But I can't post anything to server. Here is code I tried:

server

```
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public/uploads');
 form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path,path.join(form.uploadDir,file.name),function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        console.log('Success')
    });


});
   // log any errors that occur
    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
    });


    // parse the incoming request containing the form data
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    });
})
```

Html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id = "form_email" ng-submit="pushMessage()">
```

Angular

```
$scope.formMessage={};
    $scope.pushMessage = function() {

      $http.post('/customers/message',$scope.formMessage).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    };
```

Comment: give action = "/customers/message" to your form tag and remove ng-submit. also use method = "post" in your form tag

Comment: @Dinesh sr I edit question . I also want post file with input text

Comment: try using this one <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id = "form_email" action="/customers/message" method="POST">

Comment: @Dinesh Now it post file success , but how can I get data in input

Comment: You can use hidden input type for text field and submit it. For ex. <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="username" />

Comment: Or forMData() m. But formdata is browser dependent.

Answer (score 3):

i did not use this before. but ng-fileupload can do the favour for you. its simple and convinient. Here is the github documentation for that. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. Hope it will help for you

Comment: Thank for help , but I cant use this now . Voted up